# ExtJs UI Designer tool

Tags: extjs4, gui-designer

Is there a designer tool for ExtJs or Eclipse plugin for it?
I'm developing an interface which is completely similar to desktop environment.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/desktop/desktop.html

Now I'm modifying the above demo. But it is very hard and time consuming process.
Can somebody tell me about this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There is Designer from Sencha: http://www.sencha.com/products/designer

Comment: Ahh... there is a designer tool. Thanks!

Comment: np. if it suites you - please check the answer.

Comment: An old one, olnline, for version 2 of extjs [here](http://tof2k.com/ext/formbuilder/‎)

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Designer (Architect) should be your first choice. You can find it here. http://www.sencha.com/products/architect

however, if you just want to play around quickly here is another unofficial one for ExtJS - http://www.projectspace.nl/